# Turning off warning messages in GDB

Tags: gdb, warnings

I am writing a script that runs GDB and a series of GDB commands.
One of my commands `file myfile.elf` generates warning messages;

```
warning: Loadable segment ".func_addrs" outside of ELF segments
warning: Loadable segment ".aux_info" outside of ELF segments
```

I have tried using the `set verbose off` command in GDB to try to turn these off but it didn't work.

Does anyone know how I can stop these messages?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

There isn't a way to do this in gdb.

You can disable all output using "set logging".
Or you could redirect it to a file, then grep out the offending lines, displaying the rest.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to suppress the warning messages by simply redirecting stderr to the bit bucket.

Just add `2>/dev/null` onto the end of your gdb command.

For example:

```
gdb -p [Process ID] 2>/dev/null
```

At least this worked for the warning messages that I was encountering!